# How to change my javascript from inline to and external file?

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code below it functions exactly how i want it too, I just wanna know how to then move in into another .js file. Sorry I'm new with this.

So what I'm pretty much asking is how to call this code in an html document
http://jsfiddle.net/BgWjv/

HTML:

```
 <select id="selectday">
  <option>Day</option>
  <script>
   var select = document.getElementById("selectday");
   var options = new Array();
   var temp = 1;
   for(var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
     options.push(temp);
     temp++;
   }
   for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
     var opt = options[i];
     var el = document.createElement("option");
     el.textContent = opt;
     el.value = opt;
     select.appendChild(el);
   }
 </script>
</select>
```

Comment: For jsfiddle specifically, just move your JavaScript code into the JavaScript box. This is the same as adding a `<script>` tag referencing an external file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's JavaScript, not Java. And you put everything from between `<script>` and `</script>` in a file, like "file.js" and include in in the document using:

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```